# Get text from textField (from Jframe1) and change label text in Jframe2

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jlabel

I'm developing a game and stuck on player's name

I have a JFrame `GameWindow`, there is a label `labelPlayerName`. I need to change the text in that label to a text from `textBox` from JFrame named `EnterYourName`.

`GameWindow` and `EnterYourName` are two separate classes in one folder (btw I'm using Eclipse)

Comment: You could start by showing us your code

Comment: Doesn't work. I need to somehow create an instance of another JFrame in the main one, but idk how

Answer (score 0):

I would create some get/set methods in the files that you could call to change the text.

Once you do that you should be able to just do something like `name.setText(userInput.getText());`